# Session timeout after some seconds in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have created an site on Umbraco 7.1.6 it was working perfect in Visual studio 2012; when I deployed it to my hosting space I found a problem that it redirects me to login screen again and again just after some seconds. I have set keep user login to true and increased timeout but no improvement.

When I searched for that problem I found some links:

- https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/compare/release-7.1.6...7.2.0
- http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-3845
- https://github.com/Umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/commit/c936aaa51753862914591b753f7f2d7be7749cf7

First link provide me file but I do not know how to updated my current site.

In console I am getting an error.

> GET http://example.com/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js:106(anonymous function) angular.min.js:106o angular.min.js:102g angular.min.js:100i angular.min.js:79i angular.min.js:79(anonymous function) angular.min.js:80e.$eval angular.min.js:92e.$digest angular.min.js:90e.$apply angular.min.js:92safeApply umbraco.services.js:58(anonymous function) umbraco.services.js:6773(anonymous function) angular.min.js:108e angular.min.js:31(anonymous function)

Comment: Any errors in the console? And does the Network Service (or what IIS role you have) have write access to the whole umbraco website?

Comment: @MortenOC Yes, GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds throw 401 error.

GET http://example.com/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js:106(anonymous function) angular.min.js:106o angular.min.js:102g angular.min.js:100i angular.min.js:79i angular.min.js:79(anonymous function) angular.min.js:80e.$eval angular.min.js:92e.$digest angular.min.js:90e.$apply angular.min.js:92safeApply umbraco.services.js:58(anonymous function) umbraco.services.js:6773(anonymous function) angular.min.js:108e angular.min.js:31(anonymous function)

Comment: I believe Umbraco 7 require a full trust hosting, and it needs to support forms authentication. What hosting provider are you using? @syedAhsanJaffri

Comment: @MortenOC http://www.hosterpk.com/
i have enabled form authentication too.
On my local deployment IIS working fine when i change time on machine it behaves similar

Comment: Its properly something on the hosting. Have you tried other umbraco installations on hosterpk? Also, try to set the login time (in webconfig) to 0.

Comment: @MortenOC i have tried other cms but not umbraco

Comment: @MortenOC Thanks alot for your efforts and suggestions. problem was due to hosting environment (Permissions), I deployed on client's hosting it works perfect

Comment: post this as an answer and close this question... someone with this problem may skip to read as question is unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, especially to **@Morten Oc** who commented.

> It's properly something on the hosting. Have you tried other Umbraco installations on hosterpk? Also, try to set the login time (in webconfig) to 0.

I found out a solution that it was due to hosting environment (permissions), I deployed on client's hosting and it works perfectly.

Additionally if you do not have full trust hosting then it would not be able to maintain its session, you would have to configure session to managed in database.

For more info how to configure please refer to this post:

https://www.saotn.org/configure-sqlserver-sessionstate-for-umbraco/

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the exact same symptoms. A site ran just fine locally, using IIS Express, worked fine when deployed to Azure WebSites, but when I ran on a Windows Shared Hosting environment, the back office session would timeout somewhere between a couple seconds and a couple minutes.

I'd get a pop-up authentication window often but not always on the GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds url.

I filed a ticket, and the provider was able to replicate the issue. They said the site was running in full trust.

**After enabling 32 bit application support - the issue is resolved.**