# Umbraco Session timeout

Tags: c#, session, caching, timeout, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7.1.5, I have just created application and tested on local machine with few pages and everything works fine. In umbracosettings.config changed:

```
<keepUserLoggedIn>false</keepUserLoggedIn>
```

To

```
<keepUserLoggedIn>true</keepUserLoggedIn>
```

By this change am expecting no logout until explicitly signing out. I works fine on my local machine, Now when I deployed this application on hosting package, Backend starts logout within minute. javascript shows unauthorized errors.

```
GET http://example.com/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Entity/GetByIds?ids=1065&type=Media 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js:106
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:106
o angular.min.js:102
g angular.min.js:100
i angular.min.js:79
i angular.min.js:79
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:80
e.$eval angular.min.js:92
e.$digest angular.min.js:90
e.$apply angular.min.js:92
j angular.min.js:101
r angular.min.js:104
v.onreadystatechange



GET http://example.com/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Authentication/GetRemainingTimeoutSeconds 401 (Unauthorized) angular.min.js:106
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583127/session-timeout-after-some-seconds-in-umbraco

Comment: Have you tried increasing of **umbracoTimeOutInMinutes** value in Web.Config? It can keep session open for a quite long time.

Comment: I have Tried, it was hosting issue.

Comment: what sort of hosting issue?

Comment: As @rdans asked - it would indeed be very helpful to know what the issue was. I'm experiencing the same problem.
I just toggled  `<keepUserLoggedIn>false</keepUserLoggedIn>` to true in [/Config/UmbracoSettings.config] and now reliably reproduce the issue where the backoffice user loses authenticated session within a minute.

Comment: @pc-pdx I haven't gotten to the bottom of my issue yet, but just out of interest, are you using version 7.3.0?

Comment: @rdans It works with asp full trust mode only.